# C# : NotifyIcon is not behaving as per timeout

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an WPF application which will do certain set of tasks. I've put a NotifyIcon to display a notification to the user once the execution is completed. Below is the code used

```
var notificationTip = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
            {
                Visible = true,
                Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.WinLogo,
                BalloonTipText = "Execution completed",
            };
            notificationTip.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
            notificationTip.Dispose();
```

Ideally, the above code should behave in such a way that once the execution is completed, it should display the notification and wait for 1000ms before disposing it. And as per the Windows behavior, if the user is not using any input devices of the PC, the time shouldn't be counted. But that is not happening in my case. I ran the app and waited for it to complete and didn't use any input device (Mouse/keyboard). The notification popped up and it was there for like 3 seconds and disposed. How do I check what is wrong here?

Comment: Hmya, you'll have to explain what you expect to happen when you call Dispose() a nanosecond after you create the tooltip.  Calling Dispose() is *optional*, sometimes it is really okay to leave it up to the garbage collector to do the right thing.  If cargo cult is that important then call it in an event handler for the Closed event.

Comment: The problem here is not the Dispose method. It just cleans up,right? My worry was that the ballloontip was going away after 1000ms even when I am not using any input devices. As per Windows documentation, the timer won't count the seconds if the user is not doing anything on the PC. But that is not happening here.

Comment: It cleans up, that's the problem.  No more tooltip.  Delete the Dispose() call, get on with your life.

Comment: I commented out notificationTip.Dispose() and ran the app. Still the same behavior. I even increased the timeout to 10 sec but still the same thing is happening. The notification popup stays for like 2 seconds max.